# MySQL - How to group data by Day and Hour

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have some problem in getting the query for this sample format. My idea is select hours on that day and group it by day or select all the 7 days and group it by hours?

here is the format:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I assume you have one column of interest (`dt`, a DATETIME) and you `COUNTing` the number of rows to get the values for that table?

First, do this to see if you get the right values (but not the desired layout):

```
 SELECT HOUR(dt), WEEKDAY(dt), COUNT(*)
      FROM tbl
      GROUP BY HOUR(dt), WEEKDAY(dt)
      ORDER BY HOUR(dt), WEEKDAY(dt);
```

Second, you need to "pivot" the table.  However, you have particular columns.

See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot for how to generate the code for pivoting.

There are still a few formatting issues...

For the headings, you need to turn "0" into "Mon", etc.  Suggest you hard-code the titles.

"23" can be turned into "23:00 - 23:59" with a `CONCAT()` and some more code.

`NULL` can be turned into 0 via `IFNULL()`.

See how far you can get.  (Since this question is 3 weeks old, I don't want to put more effort into it if you have already gone away.)

Personally, I would do (and in fact *have done*) similar stuff using PHP instead of SQL.  PHP code is longer, but less contorted.

Comment: Just in case someone ends up here from search like I did, one can also do `DAYOFYEAR(dt), HOUR(dt)` in case the range spans across multiple weeks where `WEEKDAY()` may no longer be unique. Works with datetime columns.

Comment: mysql has `DAYNAME(dt)` which returns english week day name